# Filtering Hive partition table in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I have a hive table which is partitioned on many countries. I want to load specific partition data to my dataframe, as shown below:

```
df=spark.read.orc("/apps/hive/warehouse/emp.db/partition_load_table").where('country="NCL"' && 'county="RUS"')
```

It's giving me an error, though I was able to load for single partition.

below is my directory structure in hdfs

**`/apps/hive/warehouse/emp.db/partition_load_table/country=NCL`**

```
df=spark.read.orc("/apps/hive/warehouse/emp.db/partition_load_table").where('country="NCL"')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you don't just query the hive table directly using HQLContext:

`spark.sql("select * from partition_load_table where country in ('NCL', 'RUS')")`

If for some reason that is not available you can union the underlying hive partitions.
First read them in as separate dataframes and union. Something like:

`rus = spark.read.orc("/apps/hive/warehouse/emp.db/partition_load_table/country=rus")
ncl = spark.read.orc("/apps/hive/warehouse/emp.db/partition_load_table/country=ncl")
df = rus.union(ncl)`